# Hbase with Servlet and JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, glassfish, hbase

I am quite new to Hbase and Hadoop and above all new to java too. Recently started working on Hbase and Java. I have successfully installed & configured Hadoop & Hbase and also made my 1st ever java application on hbase using this tutorial 
http://autofei.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/java-example-code-using-hbase-data-model-operations/

Now, I want to connect hbase with web application using servlet and Jsp. In this regard, I made one jsp page where I get users input and transfer them to servlet to insert them into my HTable, but unfortunately I am facing this error :

```
    `SEVERE:   java.util.NoSuchElementException 
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:897) 
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<init>(UserGroupInformation.java:430) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:452) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Methods.call(Methods.java:37) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.call(User.java:590) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.callStatic(User.java:580) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.access$400(User.java:51) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.<init>(User.java:397) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.<init>(User.java:392) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.getCurrent(User.java:140) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionKey.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:435) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:180) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:155) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:133) 
    at com.Hbase.Controller.HbaseServlet.addRecord(HbaseServlet.java:89) 
    at com.Hbase.Controller.HbaseServlet.processRequest(HbaseServlet.java:67) 
    at com.Hbase.Controller.HbaseServlet.doPost(HbaseServlet.java:159) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) 
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260) 
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564) 
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I haven't done anything special just passed values from jps through parameters to Servlet and used addRecord function that mentioned in given link. Said error comes when I make instance of my HTable by this code: HTable table = new HTable(conf, "scores");

I really don't know what to do as I couldn't find any tutorial to use Hbase with Servlet and Jsp. I request please guide me how to use Hbase with Servlet and Jsp and also kindly point out me any tutorial to use Hbase in web application as I have to develop a complete web application which will be my degree project.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Finally I figure out myself the problem that why I was having java.util.NoSuchElementException, its just because of glassfish server 4.0. When I downgraded my glassfish server to 3.2, It worked as a charm..

Thank you.

Comment: Would be interesting to know the exact problem that is causing this. Perhaps some libraries interference, dependency injection, etc. I'm getting the same exception using glassfish 4 and some cassandra libraries.